# How to get the SSID of all configured WiFi networks programmatically?

Tags: android, android-wifi, ssid

I want to get all WiFi detail which i have added password.

Code:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<WifiConfiguration> configuredList = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT: WifiConfiguration is deprecated since API level 29, from its** [**docs**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration):

> This class was deprecated in API level 29. Use
>   `WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder` to create `NetworkSpecifier` and
>   `WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder` to create `WifiNetworkSuggestion`. This
>   will become a system use only object in the future.

**Original (outdated) answer**:

You can simply get the SSID from the public `SSID` field of `WifiConfiguration`:

```
List<String> ssidList = new ArrayList<>();

for(WifiConfiguration config : configuredList) {
    ssidList.add(config.SSID);
}
```

Don't forget to add the `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` permission to your *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```